# Print a date in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, datetime, date

I am looking for a LaTeX command or macro that will allow me to specify a date in a standard format which will then be formatted according to a globally set print format.

For example, I would specify a date in my tex code like so `\date{12-Mar-2020}`. 
If the global formatter is defined as `yyyy-mm-dd`, the date will be typeset as `2020-03-12`. 
I just need to tell LaTeX that `12-Mar-2020` should be parsed as a date should be typeset according to the global date format.

Comment: Do you need to input dates in the “day number-month abbreviation-year” format? Using a uniform input, for instance ISO numeric `yyyy-mm-dd` would be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2?lang=en) package.

`\DTMdisplaydate{yyyy}{mm}{dd}{dow}` *allows you to specify a date in a standard format which will then be formatted according to a globally set print format*, specified with the option `[style=iso]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=iso]{datetime2}

\begin{document}
\noindent This PDF was created on \today.\\
This line was created on \DTMdisplaydate{1695}{12}{02}{}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are several styles available:

- default
- iso
- yyyymd
- ddmmyyyy
- dmyyyy
- ... (see the manual for the others)

Comment: OK, what about dates that aren't `\today`?

Comment: You can specify a date with the command `\DTMdisplaydate{yyyy}{mm}{dd}{dow}`, and then it will be printed accorting to the selected style

Comment: Note that you should never leave the {dow} (last) field empty. See https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf